# SQL datetime - out of range error

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I have created an SQL table with a `DATETIMES` parameter of data type `datetime`. I am reading a number of rows from a csv file and I am trying to reformat the date time  (row[3]), from format `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` to the `datetime` compatible `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Print d2 yields a correct modified date format i.e. 2013-12-13 17:32:12, however using the SQL insert statement below triggers

```
Warning: Out of range value for column 'DATETIMES' at row 1
```

Would anyone have an idea on why a datetime format of this type might be rejected?

```
for row in csv_data:
    if len(row)>=17:
        indate = row[3]
        d=datetime.strptime(indate, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        d2=d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        parsed = (d2, int(row[2]),int(row[4]),int(row[5]),int(row[6]),int(row[7]),int(row[8]),int(row[9]),int(row[10]),int(row[11]),int(row[12]),int(row[13]),int(row[14]),int(row[15]),int(row[16]))
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO PR(DATETIMES,PERIOD ,DATA1,DATA2,DATA3, DATA4,DATA5, DATA6, DATA7, DATA8, DATA9, DATA10,DATA11, DAT12, DATA13) \
                VALUES("%s", %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) \
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DATETIMES=values(DATETIMES) ,PERIOD=values(PERIOD),DATA1=values(DATA1) ,DATA2=values(DATA2) ,DATA3=values(DATA3),DATA4=values(DATA4) ,DATA5=values(DATA5) ,DATA6=values(DATA6) ,DATA7=values(DATA7) ,DATA8=values(DATA8) ,DATA9=values(DATA9) ,DATA10=values(DATA10) ,DATA11=values(DATA11) ,DATA12=values(DATA12) ,DATA13=values(DATA13);""", parsed)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Are you on sql server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420728/how-to-prevent-out-of-range-datetime-value-error

Comment: I suggest inserting your csv data into a staging table first, with varchar fields.  Then use your database to cast the strings to datetimes.

Comment: Currently using MySQLdb. I am not familiar with casting but will try to find out more details.

Comment: I encountered the same issue with `MySQLdb`.  Check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420470/mysqldb-converts-timestamp-data-to-none

Comment: I forgot to add that the records (all but the datetime d2 in code above), are correctly assigned for the first row in the table. In the DATETIMES field the record reads as 'None'

Comment: Echo of Dan Bracuk mostly...Do not import into a date time field, import into a staging table with this defined as a varchar field.  Create the final table with the proper DateTime field in it and do the convert to date time there.  I've had to do this for pretty much every text file with dates I've imported.