# Zero date in mysql select using python

Tags: python, mysql, date, select

I have a python script which selects some rows from a table and insert them into another table. One field has type of date and there is a problem with its data when its value is '0000-00-00'. python converts this value to None and so gives an error while inserting it into the second table.

How can I solve this problem? Why python converts that value to None?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found the solution at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420470/mysqldb-converts-timestamp-data-to-none

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a None value in the data base, in a way. MySQL treats '0000-00-00' specially.
From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy
>   date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values,
>   and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable
>   the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.

It seems that Python's MySQL library is trying to be nice to you and converts this to None.

When writing, it cannot guess that you wanted '0000-00-00' and uses NULL instead. You should convert it yourself. For example, this might work:

```
if value_read_from_one_table is not None:
    value_written_to_the_other_table = value_read_from_one_table
else:
    value_written_to_the_other_table = '0000-00-00'
```